# What is the best way to add white space between two php include statements

Tags: php, html, include

I have something like this code. (I replaced specific words with fake ones.) The end result lacks spaces between and around the output of the includes.

When I add `&nbsp;`, it looks good, ***but is there a better way?***

```
Word - <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/fake/path.php'); ?> vs <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/fake/path2.php'); ?>
```

Result:
Word -pathnamevspathname2

Thanks

Comment: `&nbsp;` is how you set a space in HTML. There isn't really another way, no.

Comment: Can you make your example a bit more usable? If I test it I do get, and see, spaces, when it is HTML. See: https://3v4l.org/DN970 (press the small eye icon to look at the HTML)

Comment: `Word -pathnamevspathname2` doesn't reproduce, spaces are there. You have spaces near the `vs` and that's enough unless you wanna prevent browser from wrapping the line.

Comment: Do you mean that the second space, the trailing one, in `Word - ` gets removed? That's basically not possible. How are you verifying it? My guess is that you're rendering HTML and you have some CSS that's causing the space to be hidden.

Comment: More often than not I have trouble with normal spaces breaking my page design, I've never had the problem of not getting spaces that are actually there. One possibility could be that your spaces aren't normal spaces. So you might see them in some kind of editor, but you won't see them in your browser. This can happen when you've copied those spaces from somewhere else instead of actually typing them in yourself, assuming you're using a proper text-editor, and not a word-processor.

Comment: Even if I type additional spaces they get removed. They are normal spaces. No css is directly affecting this div.

Comment: Fine, can you make an [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of that? We cannot help you if we cannot reproduce your problem. My test above was not with an `include()`, but I tested that on my own server, and the spaces show up as well as expected.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I work on a fairly complicated site, so I have a hard time extracting the right amount of code. I guess I will just use non breaking spaces for this. It's a button, so it shouldn't be a problem. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes, that seems like an easy solution, and it will work, but I wouldn't be very happy with that. At some stage these hidden spaces might pop up again, and your layout might go awry. There's probably something hidden in your complex website that causes this, you just don't know what it is.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I agree. I will dig deeper. I didn't like that brute solution either.

Comment: Browsers will not render line breaks and collapse multiple spaces to a single space when rendering HTML, but they will not entirely remove spaces. PHP will similarly not affect anything that occurs outside the opening/closing tags. I'd suggest scrutinizing the generated page source and the includes.